# Simplify $\sinh (\log (x))$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

$$\sinh (\log (x))=\frac{x^2-1}{2 x}$$

However I do not see how this is done, here is an idea I had but I'm probably way off:

$$\sinh \left(\ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)\right)\right)$$

Here I can take out the constant but I do not understand what I am allowed to do with $\text{Ln}\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)$.

I am probably way off so and definitely far from completing it so could someone please help?

Comment: Use the definition of the sinh function $\sinh(x) = \frac{e^{2x}-1}{2e^x}$ ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function )

Comment: Presumably your first formula came out of a book; if so, your book is somewhat wrong, since the left-hand side of the equation makes sense for positive values of $x$ only. The equation needs a qualification “($x>0$)”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$ \sinh(t) = \frac{e^{t}-e^{-t}}{2} = \frac{e^{2t}-1}{2e^t}
\quad \text{ and } \quad e^{\ln(x)} = x.$$
So just replace $t$ by $\ln(x)$ to find your expression.

Answer (score 2):

> *However I do not see how this is done.*

That's because your second expression is $~\sinh\ln\sinh x~$ as opposed to $~\sinh\ln x$.